# how to append,add,update and delete node from xml using expat in php

Tags: php, xml, expat-parser

I am the new in php. And i want to parse xml into database. I tried this using DomDocument. But my friends suggest me to use expat2 parser. I googling for it but not the get the proper answers and only get the example for reading the xml. But i want more to add,update delete node from parser and also want to convert my xml into database. So please suggest me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it by your own. Whenever you read something from xml you pick the correct nodes and add them. Simple as that